# Some general questions regarding an implementation of VAE

Tags: python, loss-functions, autoencoders

I'm a biology student, and on my spare time trying to learn a little bit about ML, DL and math.Right now I'm working on a project in which I need to learn how a Variational Auto-Encoder (VAE) works.  While searching the web, I came across [this](https://jmetzen.github.io/2015-11-27/vae.html) implementation of a VAE, by Jan Hendrik Metzen. Even though it has great comments along the code that explains it, I hav some question to better understand the choices that was made.

The loss function:

```
    def _create_loss_optimizer(self):
    # The loss is composed of two terms:
    # 1.) The reconstruction loss (the negative log probability
    #     of the input under the reconstructed Bernoulli distribution 
    #     induced by the decoder in the data space).
    #     This can be interpreted as the number of "nats" required
    #     for reconstructing the input when the activation in latent
    #     is given.
    # Adding 1e-10 to avoid evaluation of log(0.0)
    reconstr_loss = \
        -tf.reduce_sum(self.x * tf.log(1e-10 + self.x_reconstr_mean)
                       + (1-self.x) * tf.log(1e-10 + 1 - self.x_reconstr_mean),
                       1)
    # 2.) The latent loss, which is defined as the Kullback Leibler divergence 
    ##    between the distribution in latent space induced by the encoder on 
    #     the data and some prior. This acts as a kind of regularizer.
    #     This can be interpreted as the number of "nats" required
    #     for transmitting the the latent space distribution given
    #     the prior.
    latent_loss = -0.5 * tf.reduce_sum(1 + self.z_log_sigma_sq 
                                       - tf.square(self.z_mean) 
                                       - tf.exp(self.z_log_sigma_sq), 1)
    self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(reconstr_loss + latent_loss)   # average over batch
    # Use ADAM optimizer
    self.optimizer = \
        tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(self.cost)
```

a. What is the meaning of "the negative log probability
     of the input under the reconstructed Bernoulli distribution 
     induced by the decoder in the data space" ? From what I know VAE is using a gaussian distribution, not bernoulli. Also, I thought this VAE reconstracts images, not distributions - so why "reconstructed Bernoulli distribution" ?

b. Why not simply use the squared error between the original picture and the reconstructed one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To some extent, the choice of reconstruction error is decided by the MNIST dataset, which the code you linked to is applied to. MNIST contains grey-scale images of hand-written digits, as such, they essentially are binary images, either a pixel is white or it is black. Thus, computing a reconstruction error as binary cross entropy is perfectly fine. For datasets with actual colour images, such as the CelebA face dataset, binary cross entropy might not be a good measure of reconstruction error. As you suggested, the squared error would be an option. However, images tend to be a little bit blurry when using the squared error loss, especially around the edges of objects. The absolute loss (or $\ell_1$ loss) often leads to images that are more appealing.